# Is there a way to ensure that all my ctypes have argtypes?

Tags: ctypes

I know I should specify `argtypes` for my C/C++ functions since some of my calls would otherwise result in stack corruption.

```
    myCfunc.argtypes = [ct.c_void_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_void_p)]
    myCfunc.errcheck = my_error_check
```

In fact, I would like to verify that I did not forget to specify function prototypes (`argtypes`/`errcheck`) for any of my about 100 function calls...

Right now I just grep through my Python files and visually compare against my file containing the prototype definitions.

Is there a better way to verify that I have defined `argtypes`/`errcheck` for all my calls?

Comment: Hmm, I tried using `getattr` but `argtypes`, `restype` and `errcheck` all have defaults (None, c_long, and None; respectively).  since those could be valid explicit settings as well, that trick didn't work.  Unless your argtypes are never the defaults, that is.

Comment: It seems to be an issue of methodology. Use namespaces. Define function pointers systematically using a list that has each name, prototype, and optional error check function. Always use the constructed namespace instead of `CDLL` or `WinDLL` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mention of namespaces by @eryksun made me wrap the dll in a class that only exposes the explicitly annotated functions. As long as the dll doesn't have the function names "annotate" or "_error_check" (which my didn't), the following approach seems to work for me:

```
import ctypes as ct

class MyWinDll:
    def __init__(self, dll_filename):
        self._dll = ct.WinDLL(dll_filename)
        # Specify function prototypes using the annotate function
        self.annotate(self._dll.myCfunc, [ct.POINTER(ct.c_void_p)], self._error_check)
        self.annotate(self._dll.myCfunc2, [ct.c_void_p], self._error_check)
        ...

    def annotate(self, function, argtypes, errcheck):
        # note that "annotate" may not be used as a function name in the dll...
        function.argtypes = argtypes
        function.errcheck = errcheck
        setattr(self, function.__name__, function)

    def _error_check(self, result, func, arguments):
        if result != 0:
            raise Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dll = MyWinDll('myWinDll.dll')
    handle = ct.c_void_p(None)
    # Now call the dll functions using the wrapper object
    dll.myCfunc(ct.byref(handle))
    dll.myCfunc2(handle)
```

**Update:** Comments by @eryksun made me try to improve the code by giving the user control of the `WinDLL` constructor and attempting to reduce repeated code:

```
import ctypes as ct

DEFAULT = object()

def annotate(dll_object, function_name, argtypes, restype=DEFAULT, errcheck=DEFAULT):
    function = getattr(dll_object._dll, function_name)
    function.argtypes = argtypes
    # restype and errcheck is optional in the function_prototypes list
    if restype is DEFAULT:
        restype = dll_object.default_restype
    function.restype = restype
    if errcheck is DEFAULT:
        errcheck = dll_object.default_errcheck
    function.errcheck = errcheck
    setattr(dll_object, function_name, function)


class MyDll:
    def __init__(self, ct_dll, **function_prototypes):
        self._dll = ct_dll
        for name, prototype in function_prototypes.items():
            annotate(self, name, *prototype)


class OneDll(MyDll):
    def __init__(self, ct_dll):
        # set default values for function_prototypes
        self.default_restype = ct.c_int
        self.default_errcheck = self._error_check
        function_prototypes = {
            'myCfunc': [[ct.POINTER(ct.c_void_p)]],
            'myCfunc2': [[ct.c_void_p]],
            # ...
            'myCgetErrTxt': [[ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p, ct.c_size_t], DEFAULT, None]
        }
        super().__init__(ct_dll, **function_prototypes)

    # My error check function actually calls the dll, so I keep it here...
    def _error_check(self, result, func, arguments):
        msg = ct.create_string_buffer(255)
        if result != 0:
            raise Exception(self.myCgetErrTxt(result, msg, ct.sizeof(msg)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ct_dll = ct.WinDLL('myWinDll.dll')
    dll = OneDll(ct_dll)
    handle = ct.c_void_p(None)
    dll.myCfunc(ct.byref(handle))
    dll.myCfunc2(handle)
```

(I don't know if original code should be deleted, I kept it for reference.)

Comment: You could pass through `**kwds` to the `WinDLL` constructor (e.g. `use_last_error`). You could also pop out an optional list of function definitions (name, prototype, error check) to set up the function pointers. This eliminates repeated code and generalizes well for larger projects. In general, the `annotate` and error checking functions needn't be defined in the class itself.

Comment: @eryksun I updated to call the `WinDLL` constructor externally. In my case, I'm wrapping both Windows .dll and Linux .so files (same API), so it will actually be `ct_dll = load_dll(windows='myWinDll.dll', linux='myNixSo.so')`. I also made an attempt to eliminate repeated code by defining the function prototypes in a dictionary. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dummy class that can replace the DLL object's function call with a simple check to see the attributes have been defined:

```
class DummyFuncPtr(object):
    restype = False
    argtypes = False
    errcheck = False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        assert self.restype
        assert self.argtypes
        assert self.errcheck

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(DummyFuncPtr, self).__setattr__(key, True)
```

To use it replace your DLL object's `_FuncPtr` class and then call each function to run the check, e.g.:

```
dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'path/to/dll')

# replace the DLL's function pointer
# comment out this line to disable the dummy class
dll._FuncPtr = DummyFuncPtr

some_func = dll.someFunc
some_func.restype = None
some_func.argtypes = None
some_func.errcheck = None

another_func = dll.anotherFunc
another_func.restype = None
another_func.argtypes = None

some_func()     # no error
another_func()  # Assertion error due to errcheck not defined
```

The dummy class completely prevents the function from ever being called of course, so just comment out the replacement line to switch back to normal operation.

Note that it will only check each function when that function is called, so this would best be in a unit test file somewhere where the function is guaranteed to be called.